# Wordpress Image is not resize on browser and devices

Tags: css, wordpress, image

I'm looking for so long to fix my issue with an full image background in wordpress and the image is awesome but is will not resize on browser and devices. Is there any css trick to do the job?

Here is my website http://www.social-boost.nl also the sign up form is important...... I hope somebody can help me out with this.

Comment: Pleas post the code you have tried to achieve what you are saying.

Comment: how does your question related ot `c#` ?

Comment: Hi himanshu, I have added no code because I really don't know where to start.... The image is 2.600px × 1.440px (scaled to 1.836px × 1.017px) When you make the browser smaller the image will not scale and on ipad and smartphone the image will look no good..... I'm really confused how to do this right.... I'm using an wordpress theme and kingcomposer is the page builder,

Answer (score 0):

What about cover (CSS):

```
html { 
    background: url(wp-content/uploads/2018/02/landingsbnew20182.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Updated answer to overwrite interfering CSS rules:

```
html { 
    background: url(wp-content/uploads/2018/02/landingsbnew20182.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed !important; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
    -moz-background-size: cover !important;
    -o-background-size: cover !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
}
```

Comment: Let me add this in css from my theme

Comment: You may need to overwrite the style tag you have now, containing     `background: url(https://social-boost.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/landingsbnew20182.jpg);
    background-size: contain;`

Comment: when I add I get this notification: expected end of value but found 'no-repeat'

Comment: how to overwrite the style tag?

Comment: You can't use `no-repeat`,`center`, `fixed` in the `background-image` rule. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: You'll need to look it up in your code of course :) This tag: `<style type="text/css" id="wp-custom-css">` seems to be what's responsible for your background image now.

Comment: Updated `background-image` to `background`.

Comment: Okay when I change the background to contain without the css code the image will adjust! here is my test page https://social-boost.nl/landing-page-socialboost/ but you see the image is not full screen..... and also the form will not adjust ery well

Comment: This is not the correct behaviour... This is: https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php There are probably other CSS rules interfering with your new ones

Comment: So I really don't know what to do right now to get it right. Can you please tell me what to do? I'm not an developer.....

Comment: Ok... Quickest solution I can think of now is to change all lines in my answer to end with `!important;` instead of just the semicolon.

Comment: Hi Herco, can you give me the code what I must add into the css? Then I know how it shloud be

Comment: Updated my answer. It's messy though, if this is a website that must be maintained for years to come you'll want a developer to take a look at it.

Comment: Hi please take a look know how it looks now..... the image will resize now but make the browser smaller and you will see a lot of duplicate the image..... do you know how to fix this? and the full image on my macbook is not cover the whole screen some px is overwriting

Comment: If I look at https://social-boost.nl/ in Chrome now, this is pretty much what I would expect from a single background image to fit all screens. If you want something better you'll probably need different images for different screen sizes.

Comment: Awesome did some changes into kingcomposer and it look good know! Only on Smartphone can we use an CSS trick for that? And btw thanks for helping me!!!

Comment: If the answer helped you can accept this answer, and after that I would start a new question for smartphone because that is a different problem. The problem is: you can't have a landscape image show up the same way on a portrait screen. You'll probably need a new image for portrait/mobile, and indeed use a CSS trick to make it show up when needed.